# Can an ex-RAID 1 drive (mdadm) be mounted normally?

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

I currently have a one-disk ext4 NAS using Ubuntu Server 18.04 on my LAN to which I am considering attaching another identical disk in RAID 1 using mdadm. But I am wondering if, following a catastophe of some sort, I would be able to mount one of the RAID 1 disks on another computer as a normal drive, as I currently could, or is it a case of once a RAID drive, always a RAID drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mount RAID 1 disk directly (if yes I don't know how), but you can create RAID 1 array with only one disk (from your NAS) on another computer.
For that you can use command :

```
mdadm --assemble --readonly /dev/md0 /dev/sdX (readonly)
```

or

```
mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdX
```